# Can't create column store index on SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server

Got this error when trying to create a column store index on a fact table:

> Msg 35315, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   CREATE INDEX statement failed because a columnstore index cannot be created in this edition of SQL Server.   See Books Online for more details on feature support in different SQL Server editions.

This is from select `@@VERSION`

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP1) - 11.0.3381.0 (X64) 
Aug 23 2013 20:08:13 
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2 <X64> (Build 9200: ) (Hypervisor)
```

Comment: Check the compatibility level of the database you are running it on, it could be lower than 110? - `SELECT name, compatibility_level FROM sys.databases;`

Comment: Are you sure this feature is supported in editions below enterprise?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SQL Server Standard edition doesn't support columnstore indexes. From the [version comparison](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc645993(v=sql.110).aspx) for SQL Server 2012, you need Enterprise edition.

Although SQL Server 2012 is specified here, it's worth noting that SQL Server 2016 with Service Pack 1 now allows columnstore indexes to be created across all editions. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx?f=255&mspperror=-2147217396#Anchor_2) for further details.